# Converting Universal Windows app to Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

As you can see in the title I am wondering how can I convert a UW app  to a Windows form App.. I have a weather app that uses a web service and I get the device current location and gets temperature and precipitations based on that location.

```
public class OpenWeatherMapProxy
    {
        public async static Task<RootObject> GetWeather(double lat, double lon)
        {
            var http = new HttpClient();
            var url = String.Format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={0}&lon={1}&units=metric&&appid=0bf2c880eef0aeccb66c4d403f9c5a7e", lat, lon);
            var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
            var data =  (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

            return data;
        }
    }
```

and also this location manager:

```
class LocationManager
    {
        public async static Task<Geoposition> GetPosition()
        {
            var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();

            if (accessStatus != GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed) throw new Exception();

            var geolocator = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 0 };

            var position =  await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

            return position;
        }
    }
```

and I am calling them like this:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var position = await LocationManager.GetPosition();

            RootObject myWeather = await OpenWeatherMapProxy.GetWeather(position.Coordinate.Latitude, position.Coordinate.Longitude);

            ResultTextBlock.Text =  ((int)myWeather.main.temp).ToString()+ "°C" + " - " + myWeather.weather[0].description;
        }
```

Comment: You're better off converting it to a WPF application. WinForms offers few advantages over WPF (besides a very shallow learning curve) which makes it inappropriate for modern desktop application development.

Comment: Another advantage of using WPF is that you can reuse your XAML.

Comment: so how can I do that? also can the WPF code is similar to the windows form application one?

Comment: WPF C# code is very similar to WinForms and to UWP. But interface code (XAML) is absolutely different from WinForms, but similar to UWP

Comment: so how exactly am I converting?

Comment: There is no UI code shown here. What is the reason to moving to WinForms? Eg, do you need to run on Windows 7, or do you need access to resources blocked by UWP, etc? Note that `RequestAccessAsync` will probably fail from a non-UWP app.

Comment: [Cefsharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/) can help you use chromium to accelerate your UI building.